# Iterate through an API using a list of names from a CSV file

Tags: python-3.x, api

(**i have updated my code. This seems to get all the rows, but is this the most efficent way to do this, or is there a better way to iterate through?)**

I am trying to iterate through an API using a list of names in a CSV File. Right now i am having to hard code the name into the API to get the data i want per "Fighter". i would like to automate this process, so i can run this code and it would search for every name that is listed in my csv file and populate the API with each name, gather the code and then i will store it in a list. Here is the code that i have so far.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import requests, re
from urllib.parse import urljoin
import csv

workbook = open('MMA Fighter Names.csv')
reader = csv.reader(workbook)
api = 'https://mma.now.sh/?fighter={}'

for row in reader:
    r = requests.get(api.format(row))
    data = r.json()

    name = data['name']
    nickname = data['nickname']
    fullName = data['fullname']
    record = data['record']
    association = data['association']
    age = data['age']
    birthday = data['birthday']
    hometown = data['hometown']
    nationality = data['nationality']
    location = data['location']
    height = data['height']
    height_cm = data['height_cm']
    weight = data['weight']
    weight_kg = data['weight_kg']
    weight_class = data['weight_class']
    college = data['college']
    degree = data['degree']
    summary = data['summary']

    print(name)
```

The "workbook" is my csv file and "api" is my api link. You can see the last part of the api i have hard coded a name "fighter = Daniel Cormier". i would like to change this part to a list {} and then populate it with the names in my csv file, while it gathers all the data per fighter.

From there i can write the code to store the data.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would work pretty well with a function or a [class](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_classes.asp), i'm using a function for simplicity's sake.

```
def gatherdata(fighter_name):

    api = 'https://mma.now.sh/?fighter={0}'.format(fighter_name)

    r = requests.get(api)
    data = r.json()

    name = data['name']
    nickname = data['nickname']
    fullName = data['fullname']
    record = data['record']
    association = data['association']
    age = data['age']
    birthday = data['birthday']
    hometown = data['hometown']
    nationality = data['nationality']
    location = data['location']
    height = data['height']
    height_cm = data['height_cm']
    weight = data['weight']
    weight_kg = data['weight_kg']
    weight_class = data['weight_class']
    college = data['college']
    degree = data['degree']
    summary = data['summary']

    print(name)


#Get all Fighters from the csv into this list
fighters = []

for fighter_name in fighters:
    gatherdata(fighter_name)
```

Comment: where would i put the csv variable?

Comment: @Ezzy Somewhere below the Function (def) Block. You have to pass all Fighter names into the List `fighters`as described.